# Minecraft Datapack tags not working (Traveler's Backpack mod, adding items to the accepted_tools tag)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-data-packs

**Note:** Some users suggest that this falls under the prohibited question category of moddded Minecraft tech support, but this isn't technical support, it deals with making data packs which are on-topic.

---

Never made a datapack before, bear with me. 1.16.5, trying to add items to a tag list for Traveler's Backpacks. When I issue /datapack enabled list, it shows me my file, but then my items don't behave as if they have the tag.

The file's setup is as follows: datapacks\tb_toolsplus\data\toolsplus\tags\items\acceptable_tools.json. The only file outside of the acceptable_tools.json is my pack.mcmeta, which is working fine.

The contents of acceptable_tools is here:

```
{
  "replace": false,
  "values": [
    "ars_nouveau:novice_spell_book",
    "ars_nouveau:apprentice_spell_book",
    "ars_nouveau:archmage_spell_book",
    "minecraft:bow",
    "iceandfire:dragonbone_bow,",
    "ars_nouveau:spell_bow",
    "minecraft:tipped_arrow"
  ]
}
```

If it helps, here's the [link](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/travelers-backpack) to the mod page on CurseForge, and [here's](https://github.com/Tiviacz1337/Travelers-Backpack/tree/1.16/src/main/resources/data/travelersbackpack/tags/items) one to their own files. Any help would be greatly appreciated--I'm trying to set this up for an RPG server and it unbalances things in a weird way to have only vanilla items function. Also, apologies if this is just something dumb. Like I said, it's my first datapack and my first time really fussing with Minecraft coding or in-depth commands at all :,)

Comment: Technical support includes abnormal behavior when using mods, as well as the mods themselves not working. Would probably be better to file a report as an issue on [the mod's github](https://github.com/Tiviacz1337/Travelers-Backpack/issues).

Comment: @Schism I would not call it abnormal behaviour though, it's not like the mod is causing Minecraft to crash or anything. For example, if they just set up their data pack incorrectly, it's not like the mod itself is misbehaving, it's just the data pack that is misbehaving. There isn't any evidence to prove that it's the mod that's causing the problem, so I would be against closing this question until it is proven that the mod is the culprit.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Having taken a cursory look, their datapack's acceptable_tools.json looks right, so it seems to me that the proper next step would be to discuss it with mod authors. It is a mod feature that is evidently not working. Alternatively, if the datapack itself is misbehaving, there doesn't appear to me to be enough detail here to diagnose that.

Comment: @Schism Yeah, but you can't assume that is the mod's culprit just because this one file is correct.

Comment: Is there something I can put in the datapack to test if it's the datapack or the mod feature specifically? Like I said, I've never made one before, so I don't know what features can be changed with a datapack for vanilla Minecraft, or how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I made it work with TConstruct tools. It is also my first datapack. Using the below video to download a program that makes editing datapacks easier, and my understanding of the structure, I was able to make my datapack.

I will leave you a link to the `.rar` on my [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VvJ7EUXjgyp2TObkQSG98KwdSCmqhrl-/view?usp=sharing), so you can see what I did. I don't know how to explain it, and I probably added more files than what was needed, but it works.